# Issue with "pollingInterval:" in JQuery idleTimeout functionality

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, session-timeout

I am using JQuery idleTimeout plugin from here :

**http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-mint.htm**

It worked fine when I imlemented in my code, but whenever I launch my page **it refreshes 5 times** everytime so I checked by removing idleTimeout code. And then it was not giving this issue.

After going into detail, I found if I remove or comment "`pollingInterval:2`" line of code, everything works fine, the refresh issue reolves and the TimeOut functionality still works.

Can someone help me understand what `pollingInterval:2` is actually doing.

Here is the code from Plugin

**JS:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        // setup the dialog
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 210,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                'Yes, Keep Working': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'No, Logoff': function () {
                    // fire whatever the configured onTimeout callback is.
                    // using .call(this) keeps the default behavior of "this" being the warning
                    // element (the dialog in this case) inside the callback.
                    $.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call(this);
                }
            }
        });

        // cache a reference to the countdown element so we don't have to query the DOM for it on each ping.
        var $countdown = $("#dialog-countdown");

        // start the idle timer plugin
        $.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
            idleAfter: 600,
            pollingInterval: 2, //<--- THIS IS CAUSING ISSUE
            serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
            onTimeout: function () {
                window.location = "/Home/Index/";
            },
            onIdle: function () {
                $(this).dialog("open");
            },
            onCountdown: function (counter) {
                $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
            }
        });

</script>
```

**The Dialog box it generates,**

```
<!-- Session Time Out Message box -->
<div id="dialog" title="Your session is about to expire!">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>You will be logged off in <span id="dialog-countdown" style="font-weight: bold"></span>seconds. </p>
    <p>Do you want to continue your session?</p>
</div>
```

**Here are the 2 Jquery which needs to be added:**

```
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/src/jquery.idletimer.js
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/src/jquery.idletimeout.js
```

Let me know if you need any other information!

PLEASE SUGGEST!

Comment: _"Can someone help me understand what `pollingInterval:2` is actually doing."_ - What does the documentation provided for the plugin say that it does?

Comment: There is nothing much docuentation provided, so I couldn't find what "pollingInterval" does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able find the solution to my issue so thought of sharing it:

The problem was that I was missing a line of code: `keepAliveURL: '/Home/KeepAlive'`

```
            $.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
                idleAfter: 600,
                keepAliveURL: '/Home/KeepAlive',
                pollingInterval: 2,
                serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
                onTimeout: function () {
                    window.location = "/Home/Index/";
                },
                onIdle: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("open");
                },
                onCountdown: function (counter) {
                    $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
                }
            });
```

As per this line, I am returning a message "OK" as "`serverResponseEquals:` " was looking for a response "OK". My code is in MVC so under "Home" Controller I created a ContentClass which returns "OK":

```
   public ContentResult KeepAlive()
        {
            return Content("OK");
        }
```

And it worked, my page stopped refreshing!

Thanks to all for looking into the issue!